# What's the difference between "activation" and "activation function"?

Tags: neural-networks, terminology

An [activation function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activation_function) is a function used by an artificial neuron (represented as a node in a graph) of an ANN (i.e. the weighted directed graph) which produces some output given one or more inputs to the neuron. There are many different activation functions.

In [this answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/11064/10640), an *activation* of a neuron is defined as a function of its input: specifically, it's a transformation of this input, which is performed via an "activation function".

Finally, the author of the same answer also says that the activation of a neuron can be interpreted as an *internal representation of the input*.

Is there any difference between an activation and an action function of an artificial neuron in an ANN? If yes, which one(s)?

I suppose these are just two terms that, in practice, refer to the same thing, i.e. a mathematical function, but, for some reason, in theory, some people use these two terms. If I am correct, what's this reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The activation of a unit $U$ (a.k.a. 'artificial neuron') is the **value** that $U$ takes in response to its input. $U$ passes this value to downstream units, who receive it as input. So, one could also refer to the activation as the **output** of $U$. The activation function is a **function** used to compute the activation.

For example, consider a unit that receives $d$ inputs, stored in vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$. It has weight vector $w$ and bias $b$. The **activation** is given by:

$$f(x) = \sigma(w \cdot x + b)$$

The **activation function** is $\sigma: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Notice that the unit itself takes a $d$ dimensional vector of reals as input and returns a single real number as output. But, the activation function maps a single real number ($w \cdot x + b$) to a single real number (the activation). Common choices of activation function include sigmoidal functions (e.g. $\tanh$), rectified linear functions, and the identity function (a.k.a. linear activation function).

Comment: It is worth mentioning that the values $w\cdot x+b$, often denoted $a$ or $z$, are sometimes referred to as __raw activations__.